# How to put a 2*1 array in one line?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Please don't tell me to reshape it to 2*1 because that will send second [0.] to the next line. I want the same output as mentioned in the expected one.
I want exactly the similar answer and using reshape is not mandatory.

```
def initialize_with_zeros(dim):
    """
    This function creates a vector of zeros of shape (dim, 1) for w and initializes b to 0.

    Argument:
    dim -- size of the w vector we want (or number of parameters in this 
    case)

    Returns:
    w -- initialized vector of shape (dim, 1)
    b -- initialized scalar (corresponds to the bias)
    """

    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    w = np.zeros((dim,1))
    b = 0
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(w.shape == ( dim,1))
    assert(isinstance(b, float) or isinstance(b, int))

    return w, b

dim = 2
w, b = initialize_with_zeros(dim)

print ("w  " + str(w))
print ("b  " + str(b))
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
w  [[ 0.]

 [ 0.]]

b  0
```

Expected Output:

```
w       [[ 0.] [ 0.]]

b       0
```

Comment: Could you post that as text in a code block and not as a picture of your screen?

Comment: print w.tolist()

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `reshape(-1, 1)` converting (2,) to (2,1)

```
import numpy as np

def initialize_with_zeros(dim):
    w = np.zeros(dim)
    b = 0
    return w, b

dim = 2
w,_ = initialize_with_zeros(dim)

w = w.reshape(-1, 1)
```

**Without reshaping:**

```
array([0., 0.])
```

**With reshaping:**

```
array([[0.],
       [0.]])
```